# prevent Froala adding colors to blockquotes by default

Tags: reactjs, froala

I am using Froala in my react code for email editing. And when I added blockquotes froala is adding colors to the blockquotes.

[image]

How can I prevent frola adding colors to the blockquotes.

Any help would be really thankfull

Comment: Inspect the colored text and you will get the class which is adding the color to the text and then In your css file make that color to black (or something) by overwriting the css rules. Apart from the questin I have a doubt that how are you able to capture what the user is typing in the editor

Comment: @GayatriDipali making changes in my css file dosen't work. Let's say I am sending this content as a mail to user or as a plain html with inline styles to other source then it is not going to work right ?

Comment: Can you please answer my second question?

Comment: onModelChange is a function that will be called when a user types something. https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/framework-plugins/react/